# Making multi level menu scale with screen size

Tags: html, css

I coded a multi level menu with pure HTML and CSS, which looks and works fine right now, there is just one Problem: on a smaller screen the dropdown doesnt start with the menu itself, its shifted to the right (because of the position i gave it). Here are 2 pictures to showcase what I mean:

[how it should always look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRt5U.png);
[what it looks like on a smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGq4u.png)

Does anybody know how I can always start the dropdown at the same width with the menu itself?
If possible the solution should be HTML CSS only but JS would also work (I can't use JQuerys tho).

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white !important;
  margin-top: -80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: start;
}

.dropdown-sub .dropbtn {
  background: url('https://innovation.siemens.com/api/v4/media/50514fe05d36e2bc5d9016add794bb31/thumbnail/strategy/full') right no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 15px;
}

.dropdown-sub .dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #DFDFD9;
}

.dropdown-content-sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 557px;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 743px;
  /*block width*/
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 557px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 557px;
  /*block width*/
  left: 106px;
}

.before .dropdown-content {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #DFDFD9;
}

.during .dropdown-content {
  height: 175px;
  background-color: #DFDFD9;
}

.dropdown-content-sub a {
  display: block !important;
  width: 770px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.dropdown-content-sub a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content-sub a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content-sub a:hover {
  background-color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #00D7A0 !important;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-sub:hover .dropdown-content-sub {
  display: block;
}

.direct-link a {
  display: block !important;
  width: 557px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  color: black !important;
  background: url('https://innovation.siemens.com/api/v4/media/ee68a14c98cb9a9bfb2dcd34f4c83b19/thumbnail/strategy/full') right no-repeat, #DFDFD9;
  background-size: 20px 15px;
}

.direct-link a:hover {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.links .dropdown-content {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  width: 1300px;
  padding: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.links .dropdown-content img {
  height: 35px !important;
}

.links .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.links .dropdown-content a {
  padding: 5px 0px !important;
  min-width: 400px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.links-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">1. Intro</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="direct-link">
        <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0035701110.#news:2377613734" href="#news">1.1 Hackathon X</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:4243998633.#news_2:0541924179" href="#news">1.2 Get started</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:4243998634.#news_3:2168954233" href="#news">1.3 Before Hack</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:4243998635.#news_4:2448033400" href="#news">1.4 During Hack</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:4243998636.#news_5:1168083238" href="#news">1.5 After Hack</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:4243998637.#news_6:3939258108" href="#news">1.6 Add-on activities</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="before dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">2. Before Hackathon</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">2.1 Define The Basics</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000000035.#:3033404513" href="#">2.1.1 Set timeline and overall planning</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036630.#_2:3852013598" href="#">2.1.2 Define overall purpose</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036631.#_3:4089751904" href="#">2.1.3 Define objectives and key results</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036632.#_4:0087073496" href="#">2.1.4 Identify crew, partners and hackatheers</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036633.#_5:0917669860" href="#">2.1.5 Brand and name your hack</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036634.#_6:2935061626" href="#">2.1.6 Set the budget</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036635.#_7:1419999552" href="#">2.1.7 Book and prep the venue&nbsp;</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036636.#_8:1597374017" href="#">2.1.8 Get the swag sorted</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0000036637.#_9:0637258078" href="#">2.1.9 Create online swag (optional)</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">2.2 Reach out to partners</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135547.#_10:0818759762" href="#">2.2.1 Reach out to partners</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135548.#_11:1546533864" href="#">2.2.2 Define hackathon challenge</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135549.#_12:3170574670" href="#">2.2.3 Set jury, criteria and mentors</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">2.3 Scout and select Hackatheers</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135550.#_13:1688645214" href="#">2.3.1 Define and organize the reward</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135551.#_14:1017243906" href="#">2.3.2 Plan a detailed timeline for scouting and selection process </a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135552.#_15:1703714785" href="#">2.3.3 Create hackateer application platform</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135553.#_16:1976669750" href="#">2.3.4 Scout for hackateers</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135554.#_17:0075375065" href="#">2.3.5 Select hackateers</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135555.#_18:2797042587" href="#">2.3.6 Plan nurturing and follow-ups</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135556.#_19:3953119892" href="#">2.3.7 Set up digital communication channels for guests</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">2.4 Promote the events</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135578.#_20:2687240798" href="#">2.4.1 Plan content capture</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135579.#_21:3817984205" href="#">2.4.2 Create a website</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135580.#_22:3502053248" href="#">2.4.3 Plan social media activities</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135581.#_23:1351165120" href="#">2.4.4 Promote event online</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135582.#_24:0485310212" href="#">2.4.5 Track online performance </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">2.5 Plan onsite details</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135583.#_25:4095718694" href="#">2.5.1 Plan a detailed agenda of the hackathon</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135584.#_26:1142691469" href="#">2.5.2 Order food and book accommodations </a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135585.#_27:3410510472" href="#">2.5.3 Plan transportation and entertainment</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135586.#_28:0444596515" href="#">2.5.4 Plan swag amount</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135587.#_29:0489582228" href="#">2.5.5 Send out info packs</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135609.#_30:3386971795" href="#">2.5.6 Prep awards and certificates</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown during">
    <button class="dropbtn">3. During Hack</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">3.1 Welcome and introduce partners and hackatheers</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135610.#_31:0444075152" href="#">3.1.1 Check venue before guests arrive</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135611.#_32:1091248071" href="#">3.1.2 Welcome guests and make an introduction</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">3.2 Run the hackathons</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135612.#_33:0033520178" href="#">3.2.1 Lead teams through the schedule</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135613.#_34:3254046935" href="#">3.2.2 Run mentor sessions</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135614.#_35:1308090383" href="#">3.2.3 Take care of food</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">3.3 Run the pitch day</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135615.#_36:2335817133" href="#">3.3.1 Introduce the pitch and run pitch presentations</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135616.#_37:3725504013" href="#">3.3.2 Conduct speed panels (optional)</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135617.#_38:3146793953" href="#">3.3.3 Host virtual streaming and voting (optional)</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135618.#_39:0983766271" href="#">3.3.4 Support jury deliberation and announce winners</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">4. After Hackathon</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">4.1 Celebrate Event Externally</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135640.#_40:3047837960" href="#">4.1.1 Update website</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135641.#_41:4028188397" href="#">4.1.2 Conclude event on social media </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">4.2 Thank your crew and partners</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135642.#_42:1460142610" href="#">4.2.1 Send thank you messages</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135643.#_43:4005956215" href="#">4.2.2 Collect feedback</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135644.#_44:3069201265" href="#">4.2.3 Summarize knowledge and learnings in a report</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-sub">
        <button class="dropbtn">4.3 Follow up with hackatheers</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content-sub">
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135645.#_45:2421756627" href="#">4.3.1 Send thank you messages</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135646.#_46:3597131990" href="#">4.3.2 Collect feedback</a><br />
          <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135647.#_47:1935408635" href="#">4.3.3 Initiate the nurturing process</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="direct-link">
        <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:4243998638.#news_7:3715379917" href="#news">4.4 Repeat</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown links">
    <button class="dropbtn">Links &amp; Downloads</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content links">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div>
            <p class="links-title">
              Links:
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>
            <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135648.#_48:3664631091" href="#">some link</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135649.#_49:3606295684" href="#">another link</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135671.#_50:3606295684" href="#">another link</a> <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:0001135672.#_51:3606295684" href="#">another link</a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p class="links-title">
            Downloads:
          </p>
          <p>
            
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown links">
    <button class="dropbtn">Contacts</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content links">
      <p class="contact-name">
        Max Mustermann
      </p>
      <p>
        <a data-ste-link-id="2833466586.-editor3/cke-138-contents:3211328197.mailto:name@bla.de:0922655718" href="mailto:name@bla.de">Max.Mustermann@gmail.com</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried just making both of them 100% screen size but that didn't work well. Our Platform provider has like 10% Padding around their page which messes with my code.

Comment: Why `left:557px;` - seems oddly specific

Comment: You're using float and position:absolute, both of these are classic ways of saving up trouble for later. Using position:absolute basically means you have to tune the whole thing for every concevable screen size with endless breakpoints and new positions. Try to keep everything in flow until it has to be otherwise, also, I'm pretty certain you will need javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D it is oddly specific. Its the exact width, the 4 Menu items (1. Intro, 2. Before, 3. During, 4. After) need so you can actually access the hover from the last Menu item

Comment: If you give the parent list item `position: relative` you can position the sub-menus *in relation* to that parent rather than to the viewport. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/njxVrv